# Why does my mass calculator not work properly with spaces?

Tags: c++, string, spaces

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

/*
Function Name: weightConv
Purpose: To take the weight and convert the following number to the coressponding weight unit
Return : 0
*/
  double weightConv(double w, string weightUnit)
{

      if (weightUnit == "g" || weightUnit == "G" )
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 0.035274 << "oz";
    else if (weightUnit == "oz"||weightUnit == "OZ"||weightUnit == "oZ" ||weightUnit == "Oz")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w / 28.3495 << "g";
    else if (weightUnit == "kg"||weightUnit == "KG"||weightUnit == "Kg" ||weightUnit == "kG")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 2.20462 << "lb";
    else if (weightUnit == "lb" ||weightUnit == "LB" ||weightUnit== "Lb" ||weightUnit == "lB")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 0.453592 << "kg";
    else if (weightUnit == "Long tn" ||weightUnit == "LONG TN"|| weightUnit == "long tn" || weightUnit == "long ton")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 1.12 << "sh tn";
    else if (weightUnit == "sh tn" || weightUnit == "SH TN")
        cout << " Mass = " << w / 0.892857 << " Long tons";
    else if (weightUnit == "s" || weightUnit == "S")
        cout << " Mass = " << w * 6.35029 << "stones";
    else
        cout << "Is an unknown unit and cannot be converted";

    return 0;   
}// end of weightCov function


int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {

        double mass;
        string unitType;
        cout << "Enter a mass and its unit type indicator(g,kg,lb,oz,long tn,or sh tn)" << endl;
        cin >> mass >> unitType;

            // Output Results
            cout << weightConv(mass, unitType) << endl;

    }// end of for loop
}// end of main
```

The weight units without the spaces work great. The problem is the Long tn(Long ton) and sh tn (short ton) unit don't work, I'm assuming it is because of the space between the string. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, convert the User Input to upper case or lower case before you compare.  See the functions `std::tolower` and `std::toupper`.  This will reduce the number of compares.

Comment: Also, consider using `switch` instead of the `if-then-else-if` ladder.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: `switch` is only for integer types, not strings.

Comment: My bad, I thought the OP was only recognizing single letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::istream`'s `operator>>(std::string &)` that you use here:

```
cin >> mass >> unitType;
```

reads whitespace-delimited tokens. That means that when you enter `"12 long tn"` into the input stream, `mass` will be `12.0`, and `unitType` will be `"long"`.

A solution to your problem can involve `std::getline`, as in

```
std::cin >> mass;
std::getline(std::cin, unitType);
```

this will read until the next newline. However, this does not strip leading whitespaces the way `operator>>` does, so you'd be left with `" long tn"` instead of `"long tn"`. You'll need to explicitly ignore those whitespaces like so:

```
std::cin >> std::ws;
```

This ultimately leaves you with

```
std::cin >> mass >> std::ws;      // read mass, ignore whitespaces
std::getline(std::cin, unitType); // the rest of the line is the unit
```

Note that this does not remove *trailing* whitespaces, so if your user types `"12 long tn "`, it will not recognize the unit. If this is a problem, you'll have to strip them manually from the end of `unitType`.

Comment: The getline function seems like it would be a more suitable solution. The problem is I've tried using it before but I tried using it like this. getline(cin,mass,UnitType). This unfortunately raises an error because it doesn't like that mass has a double as a data type. Is there anyway for it to be accepted?

Comment: `getline` does unformatted input, so it will always give you a string; you cannot ask it for a `double`, no.

Answer (score 0):

`istream::operator>>` tokenizes on whitespace characters. When you enter `sh tn`, only `sh` will get saved in `unitType` and `tn` will be left in the stream.

When you get a `sh` or `long` in the stream, check for another token and see if it's `tn`. A robust solution would probably be a `Unit` class with a free function `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream, Unit&)` that does the stream extraction.